# Automatically lazily resolving components in Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, lazy-initialization, constructor-injection

It is possible to lazily resolve a component in Castle Windsor by registering LazyOfTComponentLoader in the container and resolving a `Lazy<T>` as specified [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx):

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<ILazyComponentLoader>().ImplementedBy<LazyOfTComponentLoader>(),
   Component.For<ISomeService>().ImplementedBy<ServiceImpl>().LifestyleTransient()
   );

var lazy = container.Resolve<Lazy<ISomeService>>();

lazy.Value.DoSomething();
```

However, is it possible to **register** a component in the container so that it is *always* resolved as a `Lazy<T>` without the need to specify Lazy in the resolve call?

Specifically, I'm wondering how to inject Lazy components into controllers in an MVC project when using constructor injection.

EDIT: You can specify `Lazy<ISomeService> someService` as a parameter in the controller's constructor as can be seen [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/). However, is there a way of ensuring that a component is resolved lazily through the registration process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to resolve a lazy loaded instance of component, you will need to do a `Resolve<Lazy<ISomeService>>()`. The function lazy.Value, will do the actual resolving of the component. If you would do a resolve you will directly get your component.

If you really want to have a component which is resolved only upon first use without the use of Lazy, you could resort to writing an interceptor.

Good luck,
Marwijn.